# Ubuntu terminal Use the system fixed width font

Tags: command-line, gnome, fonts

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME Terminal 3.34.2 and I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question, so please advise.

I want to set "Monaco" as default font for terminal in preferences, however option *Use the system fixed width* font is gone and I can't find solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Monaco font is preinstalled or did you install?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't have to be monaco, this question stands for any non-fixed width font.